# Cannot use static variable's method

Tags: java, class, oop, static

A class have a static variable, but I cannot use it outside the class.

Here is the code. I cannot use `Cache.login.hget("a", "b")`, it says `Cannot access hset(...) in com.example.cache.HashCache`

Cache.java:

```
public class Cache {
    public static HashCache login;
    public Cache(String redisUrl) {
        Jedis redis = new Jedis(redisUrl);
        Cache.login = new HashCache(redis, "name");
    }
}
```

HashCache.java:

```
class HashCache {
    private Jedis jedis;
    private String key;

    public HashCache(Jedis jedis, String key) {
        this.jedis = jedis;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String hget(String field) {
        return jedis.hget(key, field);
    }

    public void hset(String field, String value) {
        jedis.hset(key, field, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Is it `hget` or `hset`?

Comment: I notice `class HashCache` doesn't have the `public` keyword.  Are you trying to use that class from another package?  It won't work with out the public.

Comment: @markspace Yes, you are right! I'm too careless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was the right answer, I'll put it here:  You have to also add the `public` keyword to the class `HashCache`.  All classes/methods etc. being used outside of a package must be `public` or they are inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

The class HashCache should be declared as public and generally whenever we face an issue where we cannot access a piece of code, its mostly due to access modifier.